# HTTPS .htaccess Rewrite for parked domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, https

I have two domain 'domain.in' and 'domain.com'. The domain.in is parked to domain.com. I have SSL for domain.com So what I need is

1) If the user visit `www.domain.com` it should redirect to `https://www.domain.com`

2) If the user visit `www.domain.in` it should use http.

I know this can done through '.htaccess' file.

Can any one help me for this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Updated Code for fix. 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.in$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I did a small change, I request you to review my change. It was not working . After i did the change it works fine. I modified you code.

Comment: IT has one more bug , if i use domain.in it work fine but if i use domain.in/login.php it is redirect to https://domain.com/login.php.

Comment: NO that shouldn't be. If you see my 2nd rule it redirects to `http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}` which means `http://domain.in/login.php` are you sure you don't have any other .htaccess or code somewhere doing this redirect for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?ouncebook\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?ouncebook\.in$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This is my complete code. I am not sure what all on this.